# Regex to split a paragraph after each period but don't split after abbreviations

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a paragraph into sentences. So that means splitting it after each period, but I also have to consider that the sentence can contain abbreviations for instance Anniv. Limnol. inc. etc. I made a regex using lookbehind to match any abbreviations that were before the period. I dynamically create the regex following a list of abbreviations like so:

```
    String regex = "(?<!abbrev1)(?<!abbrev2)\\.";
    //abbrev 1 and abbrev 2 are just examples the regex I use is much longer
    //Then I split the paragraph

    paragraph.split(regex);
```

This works but the problem is when I have an abbreviation like U.S.A. OR R.A.F., in this conditions it doesen't

Any help would be kindly appreciated
Edit: I've come up with this
 http://regexr.com?37rb3

But id does not work in Java, Any ideeas why it doesen't work?

Comment: I doubt RegEx is suited to this.  It needs some type of parser.  RegEx is powerful, but it is not magic.

Comment: How about a negative lookbehind with `[A-Z]`?

Comment: Well I can't really use [A-Z] because the abbreviations are very random

Comment: Any suggestions then on how to do this splitting?

Comment: Are there any abbreviations like `A .B. C` (with space near `.`) that shouldn't be split?

Comment: Yes, this should be that kind of abbreviation: W. Va.which stands for West Virginia

Comment: Sorry but should we split between `NBA` and `NHL` in case of sentence like `I like N.B.A. N.H.L is not for me.`?

Comment: Hello, do you have any idea why this doesn't work in Java. I already double escaped the . character

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you include the period(s) with your abbreviations rather than representing them separately. Alternatively, you can represent `U.S.A.` as `U.S.A` with your current regex style.